# tool tips do not display in this example

Tags: nvd3.js

In this fiddle, the tool tips are not working. Does anyone know why?
http://jsfiddle.net/yDk6z/1/

```
nv.models.scatterPlusLineChart();
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include the following JS in your project.

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js

```
 <h2>Promises not kept NOTHING CHNAGED HERE</h2>
 <div id="chart" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions">
   <svg></svg>
</div>
```

[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/yDk6z/2/)

Comment: Where did that d3.v3.min.js file come from? It is different than what comes from the official d3 site.